# LightningBolt script in FPS Constructor from Asset Store

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have downloaded FPS Constructor from Asset Store, however, it's made for an older Unity API. I have tried to fix it, I mostly understand it, but I have met a C# script (I'm not familiar with C#) and don't know how to fix it!
Here's the full script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class LightningBolt : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public int zigs = 100;
    public float speed = 1f;
    public float scale = 1f;
    public Light endLight;
    [HideInInspector] public bool emits = false;

    Perlin noise;
    float oneOverZigs;
    private Particle[] particles;

    void Start()
    {
        oneOverZigs = 1f / (float)zigs;
        particleEmitter.emit = false;

        particleEmitter.Emit(zigs);
        particles = particleEmitter.particles;
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        if(target == null)
            return;
        if(!emits){
            return;
        }
        endLight.intensity = 1;
        if (noise == null)
            noise = new Perlin();

        float timex = Time.time * speed * 0.1365143f;
        float timey = Time.time * speed * 1.21688f;
        float timez = Time.time * speed * 2.5564f;

        for (int i=0; i < particles.Length; i++)
        {
            Vector3 position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, target.position, oneOverZigs * (float)i);
            Vector3 offset = new Vector3(noise.Noise(timex + position.x, timex + position.y, timex + position.z),
                                        noise.Noise(timey + position.x, timey + position.y, timey + position.z),
                                        noise.Noise(timez + position.x, timez + position.y, timez + position.z));
            position += (offset * scale * ((float)i * oneOverZigs));

            particles[i].position = position;
            particles[i].color = Color.white;
            particles[i].energy = 1f;
        }

        particleEmitter.particles = particles;

        if (particleEmitter.particleCount >= 2)
        {
            if (endLight)
                endLight.transform.position = particles[particles.Length - 1].position;
        }
    }   

    void EmitCharge (bool s) {
        emits = s;
        endLight.intensity = 0;
    }

    /* C
     */
    void Target (Transform t) {
        target = t;
    }
}
```

And here's the error screenshot.
[image]

If you don't see it fully - copy-pasted descriptions:

1. > Assets/Plugins/FPS Constructor V1/Demo Assets/Weapons/PlasmaBeam/LightningBolt.cs(24,19): error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.Component` does not contain a definition for `emit` and no extension method `emit` of type `UnityEngine.Component` could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
2. > Assets/Plugins/FPS Constructor V1/Demo Assets/Weapons/PlasmaBeam/LightningBolt.cs(26,19): error CS1061: Type`UnityEngine.Component` does not contain a definition for `Emit` and no extension method `Emit` of type `UnityEngine.Component` could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
3. > Assets/Plugins/FPS Constructor V1/Demo Assets/Weapons/PlasmaBeam/LightningBolt.cs(27,31): error CS1061: Type`UnityEngine.Component` does not contain a definition for `particles` and no extension method `particles` of type `UnityEngine.Component` could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
4. > Assets/Plugins/FPS Constructor V1/Demo Assets/Weapons/Plasma Beam/LightningBolt.cs(58,19): error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.Component` does not contain a definition for `particles` and no extension method `particles` of type `UnityEngine.Component` could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
5. > Assets/Plugins/FPS Constructor V1/Demo Assets/Weapons/Plasma Beam/LightningBolt.cs(60,23): error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.Component` does not contain a definition for `particleCount` and no extension method `particleCount` of type `UnityEngine.Component` could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Comment: "particleEmitter" seems to not be declared anywhere... You haven't edited the code at all? Or oh, did you run the unity upgrade-thing?

Comment: the `Component.particleEmitter` was removed in 5.6: [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-particleEmitter.html)

Comment: @Frederik I'm using Unity 5.5.1f1

Comment: But the unity upgrader likely removed vital parts since Component.particleEmitter was decrepted earlier, but was actually fully removed in 5.6. You don't remove things right away, you give people a chance to stop using it before you actually remove it. Check my answer, I'm certain it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Component.particleEmitter was removed in 5.6. You should use GetComponent to get the ParticleEmitter component. Add these lines and it should work better:

```
ParticleEmitter particleEmitter;

void Start()
{
    particleEmitter = GetComponent<ParticleEmitter>();
```

Let me know if anything else isn't working! If you ran the Unity script-upgrade thing, chances are there might be!

Comment: I used `[HideInInspector] public new Component particleEmitter = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();` -> failure

Comment: Do it like I wrote instead. Declare a class variable namned particleEmitter then set it with getcomponent in Start()